# How do waves get reflected at open end of an organ pipe?

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection, boundary-conditions

Inside and outside of an open organ pipe usually medium used to be same (if i am not wrong) i.e Air, so in order to get standing wave reflection of wave is needed ( opp.in direction nd of same frequency). but how wave can get reflected at an open end without even changing medium? 
none of my teachers able to answer it in a satisfied way. 
Any help will be appericiated.

Comment: Does it help to look at a string with different terminations: https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/wave-on-a-string  ?

Comment: The general rule is that ***any*** kind of discontinuity in the media may create reflection. The wave solutions on one side of the discontinuity differs from the other side and ***waveform continuity*** at this point may enforce a reflecting wave.