# Open-open pipe standing waves

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions

What is the physical explanation for how a travelling wave sent down an open-open end pipe reflect from the ends (even though they are open) to form a standing wave?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384074/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150929/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

A wave propagating through a wave guide of a constant wave impedance does not reflect, but does partially reflect from the place where the wave impedance of the wave guide changes. For example, if you connect a 75-Ohm cable to a 50-Ohm input of an oscilloscope, then a high frequency signal would partially reflect from the connection. Similarly, the wave impedance of a pipe is different from the wave impedance of the open space, so the wave partially reflects and forms a standing wave in the pipe.

This is valid for all types of waves, electromagnetic, sound, etc., as a result of the [Huygens-Fresnel principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) in an odd number of dimensions. In contrast, waves in an even number of dimensions, such as on water, reflect back, even if the wave impedance is constant. For example, if you drop a rock in a lake, the wave does not just circle out leaving the center undisturbed (like a light flash would). Instead, the wave also reflects back and forms a standing wave in the center.

It is possible to use a transformer to match impedances of two wave guides. Any TV antenna has a small 4:1 transformer matching the 300-Ohm antenna to a 75-Ohm coaxial cable. Another example is the top of the acoustic guitar that acts as a matching transformer between the strings and the air. This explains why an electric guitar is so quiet without amplification, but has a longer sustain (the wave reflects back to the string). Different shapes and geometries at the ends of the pipe would act as transformers and change how much of the wave is reflected. This is why musical instruments like the tuba have the expanding end (to minimize the sound reflections and increase the volume).

Comment: You haven’t actually given an explanation for the phenomena; what’s the definition of impedance and how does the impedance change at the boundary?

Comment: @cms Have you checked the Huygens principle linked in my answer? Each point of the wavefront is a source of a new wave that goes in all directions, including backward. However, the backward wave is canceled out on two conditions (1) the space has an odd number of dimensions and (2) there is no change in the medium. When the geometry of the medium changes, the back wave does not cancel. So the fact that the wave reflects is natural, as it does not reflect only in special circumstances. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance - and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_impedance

Comment: You just concisely described the phenomena. i would exchange your comment and answer. Just providing a link to an answer is generally frowned upon on SE; a small paragraph (like your comment) would be sufficient. Perhaps: “Huygens principle explains this because ... you can find more about it by searching for wave impedance (link here) or specifically for sound (here)”. </constructive criticism>

Comment: @cms I see the Huygens principle as the theoretical foundation for the answer, but not the answer itself. I see the wave impedance as the answer. For example, when you match the cable impedance to the impedance of the high frequency input, you don't ponder the Huygens principle, you solder matching resistors. In any case, I hope there is enough information here for anyone with any background to understand the phenomenon.

Comment: Can someone else in the forum confirm or deny @saphesphere assumptions that it is natural for waves to propagate backward as well as forward? Is that the correct interpretation? I mean no disrespect by all means with this question, just curious

Comment: @RobertoValente Not assumptions, but the fact called the Huygens  principle. Please use the link in my answer to read about it in Wiki. Imagine a wave on the surface of water. How is this wave created? At each point water moves up and down that affects neighboring points 360 degrees around. So each point of the wave generates a new wave that goes equally in all directions from that point. This is called the Huygens principle. Then the 360-degree waves from each point add together into the actual wave that we see. Sometimes it works out such that the back wave cancels, other times it doesn't.

Comment: I am aware of the principle. But I think your interpretation might be slightly incorrect though I’m no expert. A third opinion would be welcome but I’m not sure I’ll get that in this forum

Comment: Why would a wave for example, reflect back in the water but not in sound or light? Can you provide any source explaining this issue?

Comment: Of course. Here is the link to the explanation by Kevin Brown: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath242/kmath242.htm (if you search for "dimensions", you'd get right to it. Good luck! :)

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, in this article he never mentions the wave reflecting back, only spreading outwards without a unit velocity. See: “For the case of two dimensional space (...) We can still solve the wave equation, but the solution is not just a simple spherical wave propagating with unit velocity.  Instead, we find that there are effectively infinitely many velocities, in the sense that a single pulse disturbance at the origin will propagate outward on infinitely many "light cones" (and sub-cones) with speeds ranging from the maximum down to zero.”

Comment: The wave propagates in all directions from every point according to the Huygens principle. Kevin shows that in a uniform medium in an odd number of dimensions this wave just moves forward. This means that the back wave generated according to Huygens completely cancels. Change any condition and it would not completely cancel. For example, light doesn't reflect back in an empty uniform space, but put any object in the beam and light starts reflecting and diffracting.

Comment: I understand that is your interpretation, which is why I asked for a third opinion

Comment: @RobertoValente Perhaps you would have a better luck if you posted your own question with a specific problem.